# How to group values and create a bar chart

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn, bar-chart

I have the following dataframe:

```
print(df)
             type    score         hits   
    0        good       26    ...     0   
    1        good       18    ...     0      
    2        good       47    ...     0     
    3         bad        9    ...     0     
    4        good       20    ...     0     
    ...       ...      ...    ...   ... 
    1701      bad       39    ...     0 
    1702     good       94    ...     0 
    1703     good       21    ...     0 
    1704     good       57    ...     0 
    1705     good       22    ...     0
```

I want to create a bar chart which groups the instances in intervals based on the 'score'. Each bar needs to represent a specified interval on the x-axis such as 0-10, 11-20 and so on, while the y-axis shows the number of instances within each interval. It would also be nice to have the 'type' separated into two different bars, such as:
[Bar chart with two groups](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ZfVQ.png)

How can this be done using pandas and preferably Seaborn or matplotlib?

Comment: `pd.cut` and then `sns.countplot`: see [code and plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/houEW.png)

Comment: Or `ax = pd.crosstab(df['Score Range'], df['Quality']).plot(kind='bar', rot=0, figsize=(10, 6))` based on the code in the previous link.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a chart using the following code, using `pd.cut` to create the intervals:

```py
# create buckets/intervals of size 10, from 0
buckets = pd.cut(df.score, bins=range(0, (df.score.max()//10 + 1) * 10 + 1, 10))

# group by type and interval, count the scores
# remove rows were value is 0 (additional intervals were created in groupby)
# convert "type" to columns and sort the intervals
# plot bar chart
df.groupby(["type", buckets])["score"].count()\
   [lambda x: x > 0].unstack(0).sort_index()\
        .plot(kind="bar")

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use histograms on subplots, using matplotlib.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, axs = plt.subplots(2, sharey=True)
for i, word in enumerate(['good', 'bad']):
    axs[i].hist(df.loc[df['type'] == word].score, bins = 10, range=(0, 100), edgecolor='black')
    axs[i].set_title(word)

plt.show()
```

Example with random data.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"type":random.choices(population=['good', 'bad'], weights=[.8, .2], k=2000), "score": [random.randrange(0, 100) for x in range(2000)]})
```

[image: two histplots]

Edit: Two side-by-side histograms are possible, though. but they can be confusing.

```
plt.hist([df.loc[df['type'] == 'good'].score, df.loc[df['type'] == 'bad'].score], bins = 10, range=(0, 100), edgecolor='black')
plt.xticks([x for x in range(0, 101, 10)])

plt.show()
```

[image: histplot]